# R Shiny: includeMarkdown cannot render htmlwidgets

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

This rmd file render ok to html, but the output is empty in shiny. Same problem with other htmlwidets like chartJSRadar

file.rmd:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document 
--- 

```{r}  
rpivotTable::rpivotTable(data.frame(a = c(1:10) ) , rows = 'a'    )
```
````

the htmlwidget is missing in this shiny app

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    includeMarkdown('file.rmd')
  )
) 
server <- function(input, output) { }  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024390)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The code in includeMarkdown is not be executed by knitr.

Comment: Then, how do you solve it?