# Placing markdown within shinydashboard box compresses page

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

I am trying to embed markdown within a shinydashboard box, to be later deployed on a shiny server. Using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499651/rmarkdown-in-shiny-application), I have created the following:

## ui.R

```
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "xxx"),
   dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(
     column(
       box(
         title = "BoxTest",
         uiOutput('mymarkdown'),
         width = NULL
       ),
       width = 8)
  )
)
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$mymarkdown <- renderUI(HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(knit("mymarkdown.Rmd", quiet = TRUE))))

})
```

## mymarkdown.Rmd

```
## R Markdown

Test Test Test
```

This creates the following:

[image: Compressed]

If I switch to a non-markdown implementation, for example:

```
output$mymarkdown <- renderUI(h4("Test Test Test"))
```

I get:

[image: Normal]

the view I would expect.

Is there any way to avoid this compression of the page, or is there another way to deploy markdown text in a shinydashboard box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also used markdown in shiny, but with rmarkdown and includeHTML

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown) 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "xxx"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(
      box(
        title = "BoxTest",
         uiOutput('mymarkdown'),
        width = NULL
      ),
      width = 8)
  )
)   
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
    output$mymarkdown <- renderUI({  
         rmarkdown::render(input = "mymarkdown.Rmd",
                           output_format = html_document(self_contained = TRUE),
                           output_file = 'mymarkdown.html')  
         shiny::includeHTML('mymarkdown.html') 
                            }) 
} ) 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works well! I actually was just about to answer my own question - I found out that `includeMarkdown('mymarkdown.Rmd')` works and is quite clean (although it does not appear that this is documented well anywhere). If you'd like to edit in your own answer (or don't mind if I do) - I'd happily mark as accepted.

Comment: Yes, includeMarkdown does work, but it does not knit the rmd file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171890. So it will work for simple text, but R code will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

`markdown::markdownToHTML` has an option to create only a HTML fragment. It omits the HTML header and styling. Like this, the Shiny site styling is not corrupted.

```
output$mymarkdown <- renderUI({  
    k <- knitr::knit(input = "mymarkdown.Rmd", quiet = T)
    HTML(markdown::markdownToHTML(k, fragment.only = T))
})
```