# Displaying html file using includeHTML in shiny is not working with renderUI()

Tags: shiny, leaflet, htmlwidgets

I have a saved html widget (from leaflet) that I want to display in a shiny app.

Using `includeHTML()` works when it is given in ui.R, but not when dynamically called using `renderUI()`.  I have many .html files that I would like a user to choose from with a select input so I need a dynamic solution.

The accepted answer from this popular post [Display HTML file in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app) has a dynamic solution, but it does not work for me.  No error is given, and nothing is rendered.

In summary:

**Works**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  includeHTML("foo.html")
)
```

**Does Not Work**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$map <- renderUI({
     includeHTML(path = "foo.html")
   })
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024390/r-shiny-includehtml-missing-htmlwidgets-in-a-reactive-context) post is also related, but no solution was found.

Comment: This is because `foo.html` is a complete HTML file. The function `includeHTML` works for a HTML fragment: the content between `<body>` and `</body>`. But you certainly need the header. I would try an `iframe`. **EDIT**: Ah finally I'm not sure. Because you said the first option works... Strange.

Comment: For me also your 2nd option works (using RStudio's rmarkdown example as foo.html).

Comment: Could you link this example?

Comment: When using RStudio click the File tab in the upper left corner -> New file -> R Markdown. But I don't think the HTML file will be the problem. Did you check your paths? Is the file located in the www folder or is it available in the current working directory? see `?addResourcePath`

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue - you can solve it by putting dynamic html content in the iframe. This thread mentioned the solution https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2535

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that knitting an .Rmd file creates an HTML document with `<html><head><title><body>` etc. while `fluidPage()` does exactly the same. So including a complete HTML document into `fluidPage()` creates problems due to redundancy. Fortunately, there's a very easy solution: use `output: html_fragment` in the YAML header of your .Rmd file before knitting and saving it as .html document.

Comment: This is brilliant! It solved my problem by just using "output: html_fragment".   I spent half a day googling and trying everything with no luck!  Thank you! @alstoc.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution:
within `server.R` you need the following:

```
output$inc <- renderUI(includeHTML("./foo.html"))
```

please use the relative path. And in `ui.R`

```
fluidRow(box(htmlOutput("inc"), width =12))
```

Comment: Thanks but the sidebar and css background images do not work as you can know from https://github.com/nirguk/example_shiny_includeHTML/issues/1#issuecomment-1082383156